# Using multiple ternary operator in C++

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

Suppose, I want to do this using ternary operator:

```
if(i=='r') r=true;
else if(i=='b') b=true;
else if(i=='g') g=true;
```

Here, r,b,c are bool type variable declared:

```
bool r=false,g=false,b=false;
```

I want to replace if and else statements using ternary operator. How can I do this?
I have tried in this way:

```
(i=='r'?r=true : i=='g'? g=true:i=='b'? b=true:false);
```

Is it okay? How is this statement compiled?

Comment: The conditional expression have its uses, but it can also be misused to make code neigh impossible to read, understand and maintain. Not to mentions the possible problems that might come from unexpected [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: `bool r = i == 'r', g = i == 'g', b = i == 'b';`

Comment: Yes, that expression (even without the redundant parentheses) will work, but it doesn't do the same thing: it is an **expression**, and its value is `true` or `false`. The first version is a **statement**, and it does not have a value.

Answer (score 3):

why not use this code?

```cpp
r=i=='r';
b=i=='b';
g=i=='g';
```